# Suggestions for Clustering with Repeating Time-Series Data

Tags: time-series, clustering

I have an idea for a piece of analysis I would like to try, but am not sure how to to prepare my time-series data or whether the answer is an ensemble of cluster analyses (or 'other')

It's a simple multivariate cluster analysis, where one variable is a (**repeating**) event date. (every observation has the same event frequency, but the dates differ)

If one observation's date is the 1st January and a second observation's date is the 31st December, they will appear far apart, when they are in-fact adjacent.

Any suggestions for what I need to learn to handle this, or how I shoud prepare my data would be hugely appreciated.

(for information, this is a question about how to optimise the grouping of jobs. There are hundreds of thousands of jobs to be done at a minumum scheduled frequency. Being able to cluster the jobs more effectively, incorporating the time component, would help build discrete groups of jobs without excess travel between them and without having to travel further than neccessary to do out of sync outlier jobs)